# Jet SQL switch — Fill in 'n/a' for blank cells

Tags: ms-access

My query isn't working as I expect it too.
I am trying to create `best_id` and where blanks/null cells are set to `'n/a'` .

Also I use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` connection via excel to do an internal query within my workbook.

Can anyone help with this?

```
switch(
bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like '[#]N/A%',master.[Identifier],
bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like '[#]N/A%',replace(master.[Identifier],' cusip','') & ' cusip',
bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like '[#]N/A%',replace(master.[Identifier],' isin','')  & ' isin',
master.[Identifier] is not null, master.[Identifier],
true,'n/a'
) as best_id,
```

I've tried changing the wildcard to `*` but can't seem to get the cells to show n/a for blank/null ones

```
switch(bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*", master.[Identifier],
       bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*", replace(master[Identifier], " cusip", "") & " cusip",
       bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*", replace(master.[Identifier], " isin", "")  & " isin",
       master.[Identifier] is not null, master.[Identifier],
       true, "n/a"
     ) as best_id,
```